# How to customize font size in Ionic Framework

Tags: css, font-size, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic framework (with cordova) to develop mobile apps.
What I want to do is to increase the font size (in general in my app).

I've seen that in the official documentation : http://ionicframework.com/tutorials/customizing-ionic-with-sass/.
But I do not understand how to customize once sass is working.

I'm working in a tabs-based App like that : http://forum.ionicframework.com/uploads/default/269/9934610f0a08b8d2.png
I tried to manually add a class on the tab, but the result is not very clean... the text is cropped...

Is there an official way to change the font-size ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you don't need to undersand everything on Sass.
In your project directory, in

```
.../yourProject/www/lib/ionic/scss
```

There is a file named `_variables.scss` where you will see something like this :
[image]
[image]
These are font-size variables, you just have to change these and then build the ionic css file.
I suggest you to use https://prepros.io/. I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 7):

Figured I'd share what I've learnt in Ionic.

Basically, Ionic has a default set of sizes, colors, fonts for every single thing you can design and this set is stored in the _variables.scss file. This file is at lib/ionic/scss/_variables.scss

Open this file and search for what you want to alter. For example, I needed to increase the header font-size. So I searched in the _variables.scss file and found $bar-title-font-size.

It was defined as `$bar-title-font-size:             17px !default;`

Now, open your ionic.app.scss file and write something like

`$bar-title-font-size:             25px !default;`

***Remember to write the above statement before the `@import "ionic/scss/ionic";` statement.

Save the file and your changes will instantly take effect. Ionic has made it that simple!!! :)

Answer (score 7):

Search your project/www/css and edit style.css, and inside the file write:

```
{font-size:55px !important;}
```

change **55px** to whatever size you need.

Answer (score 2):

Often you want to decide when to use which icon size so I came up with the following solution.

CSS

```
/* Ionicon icons resizing css */
.ion-1x { font-size: 24px !important;}
.ion-2x { font-size: 48px !important;}
```

HTML

```
// in iconics framework
<ion-icon name="logo-pinterest" class="ion-1x"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon name="logo-twitter" class="ion-2x"></ion-icon>

// without ionics framework
<i class="ion-1x ion-social-pinterest"></i>
<i class="ion-2x ion-social-twitter"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

To make responsive font-size according to device for ionic2,
Add this in src/theme/variables.scss

```js
// breakpoint mixin
@mixin breakpoint($mq01: 0, $mq2: false, $maxmin: max-width) {
  @if $mq2 == false {
      @media ($maxmin: $mq01) {
          @content;
      }
  }
  @else {
      @media (min-width: $mq01) and (max-width: $mq2) {
          @content;
      }
  }
}

// breakpoint variables
$lg: 1170px;
$md: 1024px;
$sm: 640px;
$xs: 480px;

// responsive font size mixin
@mixin font-size-map($font-size-map) {
    @each $breakpoint, $font-size in $font-size-map {
        @if $breakpoint == null {
            font-size: $font-size;
        } @else {
            @include breakpoint($breakpoint) {
                font-size: $font-size;
            }
        }
    }
}

// font sizes

$html-font-size: (null: 16px, $md: 15px, $sm: 14px, $xs: 13px);
$paragraph-font-size: (null: 18px, $lg: 17px, $md: 16px, $sm: 15px, $xs: 14px);
```

include variable in local scss by adding: @include font-size-map($html-font-size);

```
// html

html {
    @include font-size-map($html-font-size);
}

p {
    @include font-size-map($paragraph-font-size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Ionic (4 + 5) use [CSS variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables).

However, there is no variable for the font size.  So, you can add a line like this to `variables.css`:

```
body ion-content {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

Further reading

- [Global styling in Ionic apps](https://rajsm139.medium.com/ionic-set-global-styling-d1b2d4fae11a)
- [Setting a font family in an ionic app](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-add-a-new-font-into-your-ionic-app-b7e0871ff5f4)

Answer (score -1):

I use Ionic for my apps and this is how I deal with resizing:

1. Find the class/element that you need to modify in CSS
2. Set `padding:0 0 0 0;` or to values you want (top,right,bottom,left).
3. Set font size
4. Set height
5. Set line-height

Edit: This is how I modified my tab items

```
.tab-item{
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 100px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    font-size: 40px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Roboto-Light';
    opacity: 1;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I didn't succeed to resize my tabs text/icons. The classes I tried to override are a.tab-item{} or a.tab-item i{} / a.tab-item span{}... but seems to not work

Comment: @psv can you post a bit of your code/screenshot of the inspect on your elements. Also check the edit.

Comment: using "px" doesn't seem to be a good idea, "em" is more recommended

Comment: Better to use SCSS variables for something like this.