# Ionic and user input to change the font color dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, sass

I can't conceptually jump over this pitfall. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933858/how-to-customize-font-size-in-ionic-framework) but this only helps me on creating on static css.

What I have is a Ionic (1) app with scss and I have a variable $primary: #000; that changes all font color in the app.

I could choose to change the color and save a compiled css for each font color and switch the color with ng-href. But it seems like a unnecessary/complicated way to go. What if i need to add another color?

I also have the option to use ng-style for this as [this example here](http://codepen.io/hannuraina/pen/iDgmJ) shows.

```
  <div ng-style="style" class="item">
    This is a basic Card.
    <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
  </div>
```

But it seems also as a complicated way to go since I need to change all the html template file to get it to work.

A third option could be to add Less to the project and let Less change the css in run-time. But it seems like a awkward way to to since sass is built in.

Is there any body out there who could send me a pointer/example how to do it. Or tell me how I should do it, in the best way, so the app also have easy to maintain.

Cheers!